# ggplotly - how to do an animated scatterplot with labels when NAs are present?

Tags: r, animation, label, na, ggplotly

I am using an unbalanced panel with 2 countries, 11 years, and 2 variables. One country has no missing values, while the other one has four missing years in both variables. Here is my dataframe

```
df <- structure(list(
ISO = c("BRA", "BRA", "BRA", "BRA", "BRA", "BRA","BRA", "BRA", "BRA", "BRA", "BRA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA","USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA"), 
year = c(1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990), 
y = c(1.49928137169864, 1.48826755573396, 1.4852053019613, 1.49215038590105, 1.48925247516576, 1.50012937543379, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.57689188746679, 1.58319781015294, 1.58382940099389, 1.58413234358913, 1.58337049236411, 1.58433274492085, 1.58445957772582,  1.58370284674093, 1.58291143519588, 1.58314679337981, 1.58302389868652, 1.58246620735483), 
x = c(0.673651140454928, 0.659558887085615,  0.633375124775425, 0.653921566330419, 0.654296097588995, 0.682025986688934, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.906490443503071, 0.981373633793688, 0.980293927670322, 1.00110944206308, 0.953001041098418, 0.966203553492277, 0.969308764992296, 0.944873699574678, 0.929346720968387, 0.941836758277121, 0.947643266493785, 0.966693155516413)), 
class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 1236L,  1237L, 1238L, 1239L, 1240L, 1241L, 1242L, 1243L, 1244L, 1245L, 1246L))
```

I want to create a dynamic scatterplot whith two points representing the countries moving in the x-y space as time goes by. Furthermore, I would like to label the points with the countries' name.
I could do this using `gganimate` but I prefer the style and the smoothness of `ggplotly`.

I have tried to use the following code

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
ggplotly(ggplot(df, aes(y = y, x = x, color = ISO, label = ISO, frame = year))+
           geom_point()+
           geom_text(hjust=0, vjust=0)+
           theme(legend.position="none")+ 
           theme_bw())
```

The problem is that, as the animation gets to the missing year, the label of the country which is missing disappears, and the label of the other country gets duplicated.
Instead, I would like the missing country to disappear, both the point and the label, and avoid any duplication.

This is what I would like to avoid
[image]